# Python, string is returning IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, index-error

```
get_code="https://localhost:8080/soieurow/KPP/alksdjfhlkjhekajhf?eowuiro=akleireyi&URL=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fmga%2Fsps%2Foauth%2Foauth20%2Fauthorize%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2Bname%2Bemail%2Bpostal_code%26client_id%3Dthaljlwej%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Faklsdjfhwekdisd.com%3A5006%2Fredirectcode%26nonce%3DQJT8RbymFk%26acrakdjasd%3DD1%26token%3DfkasjfhalskfhlaksjhkL61bqqADtekpH-HE55lZaX2LJH4Ii9diraseufhalksfhl%26correlation_id%3D4102479872341%26support_encryption%3Dsj2aljkadfj3%26state%3Dajk1234"
code='code'
if code in get_code:
    code=get_code.split("code=")[1][:47]
    print("i havce code",code)
else:
    print("i don't find code")
```

I am passing string, but i am getting IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please no images of code.

Comment: you better put the actual code than an image of it, we can't see the string value :)

Comment: `code=` does not appear in what you showed of the string you are splitting, in which case there would be no element at index 1.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour on how to ask questions

Comment: share the actual code so we will be able to assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index error is about the first one (`[1]`) not the second one (`[:47]`).
It's because the `get_code` string doesn't contain any `code=` string at all!
So here is what happens:

- `split` method returns the list of substrings split by `code=`; which in turn doesn't find any `code=` and returns the whole `get_code` string as an array of length 1. (i.e returns `["https://..."]`)
- But you wanted to get the second element of the returned array (as of `[1]` part) which leads to an error since the array has only one element at the index of `0`!

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is that you asked if 'code' is in the string but you split by 'code='. Fix that and the code will work as  expected.